# Matching a list with a hash table

Tags: php, redis

I’ve setup hash tables for a few items using:

```
RPUSH itemList:0 A
RPUSH itemList:0 B
RPUSH itemList:0 C

HSET items item:A A_VALUE
HSET items item:B B_VALUE
HSET items item:C C_VALUE
```

I’m currently using:

```
LRANGE itemList:0 0 5
```

To get back a list of items `["A", "B", "C"]`

How would I modify this to get an object back with `{"A":"A_VALUE", "B":"B_VALUE", "C":"C_VALUE"}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this without scripting.

If your redis version less then 2.6 it can be done only with code like this (simple php version):

```
$data = $redis->lRange('itemList:0', 0, 5);

$valueKeys = array_map(
    function($key) {
        return 'item:' . $key;
    } 
    , array_unique($data)
);

$values = $redis->hMGet('items', $valueKeys);
$ret = [];
foreach ($data as $key) {
   $ret[$key] = $values['item:' . $key];
}
```

If you are using Redis 2.6+ you can write LUA stored procedure to get data(same as php logic).

Comment: Ok. I'm using `lua-resty-redis` with `nginx` to make these database calls.  This looks pretty straight forward, I'll try it tomorrow.  My 'items' list might end up being too long for hGetAll to be optimal.  Maybe I'll run an HGET for each LRANGE result instead, although, that's a lot of database calls.

Comment: It`s just simple sample. If you HASH has many keys you can use HMGET to get just keys which present in your LRANGE query. Just 2 database calls. Edit my answer to show this way.